# Dataset with jpg import to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I've to build a machine learning model with python via jupyter notebook using tensorflow and keras. I've a Dataset of 1000 pictures. 800 of them I want to use for training the model and the 200 for testing and validation. It is for a gender and age prediction model. Now how do I import my dataset or how do I write the path in upyter notebook or google colab to import my Dataset.

What I've done is imported the packages for my project.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical, plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can upload the dataset in google colab, if the dataset is in your local system.

1. You can upload your dataset to your Google drive.

And the simplest way to share files is to mount your Google Drive in your Google Colab notebook.

To do this, run the following in a code cell:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

It will ask you to visit a link to ALLOW "Google Files Stream" to access your drive. After that, a long alphanumeric auth code will be shown that needs to be entered in your Colab's notebook.

Afterward, your Drive files will be mounted and you can browse them with the file browser in the side panel.

2. You can upload files manually by browsing to your local file system

It takes a longer time to upload in this method.

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Here are two examples for your reference:

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q
- [Dataset with jpg import to jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645275/dataset-with-jpg-import-to-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas to locate a CSV file try to give full path

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mahe\Desktop\homeprices.csv")
```

use this way
Or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

DATADIR = "X:/Datasets/PetImages" #(give your full path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I explain in a simple way in Tensorflow how to load images and labels directly from a TXT file. Hope this can help you. The following code illustrates how I did it. However, it does not mean that it is the best way to do it and that this way will help in additional steps.

For example, I am loading the labels in a single integer value {0,1}, while the documentation uses a single heat vector [0,1].

```
#Learning how to import images and labels from a TXT file
#
#TXT file format
#
#path/to/imagefile_1 label_1
#path/to/imagefile_2 label_2
#...                 ...
#where label_X is either {0,1}

#Importing Libraries
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
#File containing the path to images and the labels [path/to/images label]

filename = '/path/to/List.txt'

#Lists where to store the paths and labels

filenames = []
labels = []

#Reading file and extracting paths and labels
with open(filename, 'r') as File:
    infoFile = File.readlines() #Reading all the lines from File
    for line in infoFile: #Reading line-by-line
        words = line.split() #Splitting lines in words using space character as separator
        filenames.append(words[0])
        labels.append(int(words[1]))

NumFiles = len(filenames)

#Converting filenames and labels into tensors
tfilenames = ops.convert_to_tensor(filenames, dtype=dtypes.string)
tlabels = ops.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=dtypes.int32)

#Creating a queue which contains the list of files to read and the value of the labels
filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([tfilenames, tlabels], num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, capacity=NumFiles)

#Reading the image files and decoding them
rawIm= tf.read_file(filename_queue[0])
decodedIm = tf.image.decode_png(rawIm) # png or jpg decoder

#Extracting the labels queue
label_queue = filename_queue[1]

#Initializing Global and Local Variables so we avoid warnings and errors
init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer() ,tf.global_variables_initializer())

#Creating an InteractiveSession so we can run in iPython

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(init_op)
    
    # Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(NumFiles): #length of your filenames list
        nm, image, lb = sess.run([filename_queue[0], decodedIm, label_queue])
        
        print image.shape
        print nm
        print lb
        
        #Showing the current image
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```